# Unexplained .htaccess redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess

We got a `.htaccess` as bellow. What it should do is redirect example.com and `www.example.com` requests to `example.de` plus adding the requested page and `?lang=en`

What happens is:
1. I visit `example.com/` 
2. Get redirected
3. New URL is: `www.example.de/index-e.php?lang=en`

Notice the `www` and `index-e.php`. I have no clue where the `www` and `index-e.php` are coming from.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://example.de/$1?lang=en [R=301,L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Nothing here. In the example.de htaccess or config file ?

Comment: Test it after clearing your browser cache.